# Laravel 4 eloquent + raw query returns NULL

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

if have this relationship in my Place model:

```
public function openhours()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Hours')->select(DB::raw("IF(CURTIME() BETWEEN open_time AND close_time ,'Open','Closed')"));
}
```

and in my routes:

```
 $place = Place::with('openhours')->where('id', '=', 5)->get();
```

my table:

```
Table Name : hours
Fields : 
id          int(11)
place_id    int(11)
open_time   time
close_time  time
```

table record:

```
id: 1
place_id: 5
open_time: 10:00:00
close_time: 17:00:00
```

it just returns:

```
 openhours:null
```

When i run this query manually in phpmyadmin it works fine.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select()` used for the columns you want from the query. I think you better create an accessor for the model where you determine if the place is open. Btw why did you put the hours into a separate table?

Comment: thanx for your reply, i put the hours in a seperate table because of the different openhours for each day. i still have to put the day field in

Answer (score 2):

Add the following into your App:before filter and you will get a dump of all the queries being executed and the bindings.

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time)
{
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($bindings);
});
```

Not an answer but it might help you see how the eloquent request compares to your own SQL.

Comment: the eloquent request is just the same as my own sql and works if run it in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

don't you need more like;

```
Place::find($id)->openhours();
```

Comment: thanx for your answer! but how come with Place::find($id)->openhours(); i do get the sql request but not the place data and Place::find($id)->with('openhours')->first(); i get the place data but the openhours is NULL. is this not the same thing?